# Notepad++ plugin server down, any alternatives?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I hope this is the right sub, it has the most hits for NP++ questions.

This morning I opened Notepad++ and went looking for a JSON plugin. However, the Plugin Manager shows no plugins and returns "There was an error downloading the plugin list..."

Poking about I found the reason; the list is held at https://bruderste.in/ and his cert expired. Does anyone know of a workaround? I tried setting it to "Use development plugin list", but that didn't help (not surprisingly).

The list appears to be a text file, can it be installed "manually"?